# Vue-Nativescript Back-Navigation crashes iOS App

Tags: ios, vue.js, nativescript

I'm struggling with the proper navigation and experience a crash, once I go back to the Main-Site. That happens on my iOS device and the virtual devices.

My structure is as follows:

Dependencies in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/core": "7.1.3",
    "@nativescript/theme": "3.0.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-cardview": "2.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "kinvey-nativescript-sdk": "6.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nativescript-background-http": "4.2.1",
    "nativescript-camera": "4.5.0",
    "nativescript-fonticon": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-http-formdata": "^2.1.0",
    "nativescript-image": "3.0.1",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "7.1.0",
    "nativescript-intl": "3.0.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "1.5.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "2.0.24",
    "nativescript-ui-autocomplete": "7.0.2",
    "nativescript-ui-calendar": "6.1.0",
    "nativescript-ui-chart": "7.1.1",
    "nativescript-ui-dataform": "7.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-gauge": "6.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "8.0.1",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "8.0.0",
    "nativescript-vue": "2.8.3",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.5",
    "vform": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.17.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3"
  }
```

app.js

```
    new Vue({
      store,
      render: h => h('frame', [h(routes.login)]),
      created() {
      },
    }).$start();
```

After after the successful Login, I will be redirected to Main.vue.

Main.vue contains following (Bottom Navigation and included component for main menu -> Home):

```
    <template>
      <Page actionBarHidden="true">
        <ActionBar title="App-Name"></ActionBar>
        <StackLayout>
          <StackLayout>
              
            <BottomNavigation height="auto">
              <TabStrip>
                <TabStripItem>
                  <Label text="Home"></Label>
                  <Image src="res://home"></Image>
                </TabStripItem>
                <TabStripItem>
                  <Label text="Einstellungen"></Label>
                  <Image src="res://settings"></Image>
                </TabStripItem>
                <TabStripItem>
                  <Label text="Info"></Label>
                  <Image src="res://browse"></Image>
                </TabStripItem>
              </TabStrip>
              <TabContentItem>
                <GridLayout>
                  <Home></Home>
                </GridLayout>
              </TabContentItem>
              <TabContentItem>
                <GridLayout>
                  <Settings></Settings>
                </GridLayout>
              </TabContentItem>
              <TabContentItem>
                <GridLayout>
                  <Info></Info>
                </GridLayout>
              </TabContentItem>
            </BottomNavigation>
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </Page>
    </template>
```

The Home Component which contains the main menu, looks like that:

`<template> </template>`
and contains card which has a @tap function to go to the next page.

```
    methods: {
        logout() {
          this.$store.dispatch("clearUser");
        },
        goToPageXY() {
          this.$navigateTo(PageXY, {
            clearHistory: false,
          });
        },
      },
```

The page that is called via tap (PageXY in that case) contains this structure:

```
<template>
  <Page class="page">
</Page>
</template>
```

The further navigation in 'deeper' pages works as expected and I can use the "Go back" button as I need to.

Problem:
Once I want to navigate back to the Main.vue (From PageXY back via history-mode ON or $navigateTo / $navigateBack) the App crashes. This only happens on that page.

The error output is following:

```
    ***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
    Native stack trace:
    1   0x10de4b62e NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
    2   0x10de8c3a8 NativeScript::FFICallback<NativeScript::ObjCMethodCallback>::ffiClosureCallback(ffi_cif*, void*, void**, void*)
    3   0x10e887c90 ffi_closure_unix64_inner
    4   0x10e8886b2 ffi_closure_unix64
    5   0x7fff23f47ce3 -[UIViewController __viewDidAppear:]
    6   0x7fff23f47fbc -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:]
    7   0x7fff23e6d6a3 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
    8   0x7fff23e62284 __49-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]_block_invoke
    9   0x7fff23f6c4b8 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:]
    10  0x7fff23f83680 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke.155
    11  0x7fff24bcb250 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:]
    12  0x7fff24b9bb62 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
    13  0x7fff24b9c101 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
    14  0x7fff24b9c285 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
    15  0x7fff27a8a4f6 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*)
    16  0x7fff20106508 _dispatch_client_callout
    17  0x7fff20112ff7 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
    18  0x7fff2038bdab __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
    19  0x7fff2038662e __CFRunLoopRun
    20  0x7fff203856c6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    21  0x7fff2b76adb3 GSEventRunModal
    22  0x7fff24675187 -[UIApplication _run]
    23  0x7fff2467a038 UIApplicationMain
    24  0x10e8884f5 ffi_call_unix64
    25  0x115a85090
    JavaScript stack trace:
    file: node_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:4880:17
    at destroy(file: node_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:4046:8)
    at invokeDestroyHook(file: node_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:5455:60)
    at patch(file: node_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:5808:47)
    at file: node_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:4886:17
    at handler(file: node_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:12773:12)
    at _handleEvent(file: app/packages/core/data/observable/index.ts:296:19)
    at notify(file: app/packages/core/data/observable/index.ts:278:27)
    at onNavigatedFrom(file: app/packages/core/ui/page/page-common.ts:139:14)
    at raiseCurrentPageNavigatedEvents(file: app/packages/core/ui/frame/frame-common.ts:310:24)
    at _updateBackstack(file: app/packages/core/ui/frame/frame-common.ts:268:39)
    at setCurrent(file: app/packages/core/ui/frame/index.ios.ts:58:25)
    at file:///app/vendor.js:39242:23
    at UIApplicationMain([native code])
    at run(file: app/packages/core/application/index.ios.ts:395:20)
    at file: node_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:12548:23
    at file:///app/bundle.js:6582:10
    at ./app.js(file:///app/bundle.js:6586:34)
    at __webpack_require__(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at checkDeferredModules(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:43:0)
    at webpackJsonpCallback(file: app/webpack/bootstrap:30:0)
    at anonymous(file:///app/bundle.js:2:61)
    at evaluate([native code])
    at moduleEv<…>
    JavaScript error:
    file: node_modules/nativescript-vue/dist/index.js:4880:17: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'vm._data.__ob__')
    ***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
```

My feeling tells me, that I did mistakes when it comes to using Pages / Frames.

I would really appreciate any kind of help, since I'm struggling with that for hours already.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using frame
try this

```
this.$navigateTo(PageXY, {
     frame: 'frame',
});
```

to go back try this:

```
this.$navigateBack({frame: "frame"});
```